# Is this an improper use of "look like"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is this an improper use of "look like"? I am not sure, but I think you usually use a "noun", but in the following case I am not sure if the use of a phrase is correct.

For example:

> Your hair looks like **you dumped gel and didn't even bother spreading
>   it out.**

I am not sure if I am imagining thing, but it sounds odd, but at the same time there's the expression "You look like you could use some help."

Comment: Voting to close this as it can be looked up in a dictionary. [Ex.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look%20like). Please review [this page](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Bee - That dictionary entry explains the meaning of the phrase, and it gives two examples usages, but it does not answer the OP's question. The OP is acknowledging that the expression can be used with a noun (as in M-W's examples), but wants to know if it can be used with a clause (in this case, "you dumped gel").

Comment: It should be *dumped gel* ***in it***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use "look like" this way as long as you fix the problem Jason Bassford mentioned:

"Your hair looks like you dumped gel in it and didn't even bother spreading it out."

Google "your hair looks like someone" for many examples.